# Find all pairs in an array that sum to a given number without using HashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, interview-questions, k-sum

> Find all pairs in an array that sum to a given number without using `HashMap`.
>   Duplicate pairs are not allowed. Input array cannot be modified.
>
> input:   `{-2, -1, -1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8}`, target = `7`
>
> output: `(-1, 8)`

As it is mentioned, using `HashMap` is not allowed, so I decided to use binary search.

[GitHub](https://github.com/Ramblers-Code/CodeKata/blob/master/src/main/java/kata/array/TwoSumProblemUsingBinarySearch.java#18)

```
public class TwoSumProblemUsingBinarySearch {

    public static class Pair {

        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        public Pair(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (other instanceof Pair) {
                Pair o = (Pair) other;
                return this.x == o.x && this.y == o.y;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
        }
    }

    public static Set<Pair> findAllParis(int input[], int target) {
        int numbers[] = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
        Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<>();

        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        for (int low = 0, high = input.length - 1; low < high; ) {
            int sum = input[low] + input[high];

            if (sum > target) {
                high--;
            } else if (sum < target) {
                low++;
            } else {
                pairs.add(new Pair(input[low], input[high]));
                high--;
                low++;
            }
        }

        return pairs;
    }
}

@Test
public void findAllParis() throws Exception {

    System.out.println(TwoSumProblemUsingBinarySearch.findAllParis(new int[]{-2, -1, -1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8}, 7));
    assertEquals(1, TwoSumProblemUsingBinarySearch.findAllParis(new int[]{-2, -1, -1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8}, 7).size());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Incorporating the feedbacks, here is the answer

Github: https://github.com/Ramblers-Code/CodeKata/blob/master/src/main/java/kata/array/TwoSumProblemUsingBinarySearch.java#18

```
public class TwoSumProblemUsingBinarySearch {

    public static class Pair {
        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        public Pair(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (other instanceof Pair) {
                Pair o = (Pair) other;
                return this.x == o.x && this.y == o.y;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
        }
    }

    public static Set<Pair> findAllPairs(int input[], int target) {
        int numbers[] = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
        Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<>();

        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        for (int low = 0, high = numbers.length - 1; low < high; ) {
            int sum = numbers[low] + numbers[high];

            if (sum > target) {
                high--;
            } else if (sum < target) {
                low++;
            } else {
                pairs.add(new Pair(input[low], input[high]));
                high--;
                low++;
            }
        }

        return pairs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Typo in method name as pointed out by [@Stingy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190395/find-all-pairs-in-an-array-that-sum-to-a-given-number-without-using-hashmap/190429#190429). Should be `findAllPairs`.
2. Accessing wrong array: You are reading values from `input` instead of your sorted copy `numbers`. This is probably a typo. E.g. `int sum = input[low] + input[high];` should be `int sum = numbers[low] + numbers[high];`
3. Your `for` loop has an empty update statement, this isn't wrong per-se but a bit unusual. Consider an alternative using `while` instead:

   ```
   int low = 0, high = numbers.length-1;
   while (low < high) {
       int sum = numbers[low] + numbers[high];
       //...
   }
   ```
4. Insufficient test: As evidenced by its failure to catch the bug in 2. the test is too limited to be of much help. Consider checking more than one example (especially corner-cases like an empty input array) and checking against the expected output instead of just its size.

Comment: ooooo...indeed typo it should be `numbers` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent duplicate pairs by incrementing/decrementing your counters not only once, but until they point to a number that is greater/lesser than the number they previously pointed to. That way, you can store the pairs in a `List` instead of a `Set`, which will probably be faster, because the `List` doesn't need to check whether it already contains a pair that is equal to the one being added.

Also, there is a typo in your method names `findAllParis`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid creating pairs that will be discarded as duplicates.  Just advance to the next *different* value instead of simply the next value here:

```
            pairs.add(new Pair(input[low], input[high]));
            high--;
            low++;
```

then becomes

```
            pairs.add(new Pair(numbers[low], numbers[high]));
            for (final int n = numbers[high--];  low < high && numbers[high] == n;  --high)
                ;
            for (final int n = numbers[low++];   low < high && numbers[low]  == n;  ++low)
                ;
```

And then we can use a plain list instead of a set:

```
public static List<Pair> findAllPairs(int input[], int target) {
    int numbers[] = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
    Arrays.sort(numbers);

    ArrayList<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int low = 0, high = input.length - 1;  low < high;  ) {
        int sum = numbers[low] + numbers[high];

        if (sum > target) {
            --high;
        } else if (sum < target) {
            ++low;
        } else {
            pairs.add(new Pair(numbers[low], numbers[high]));
            for (final int n = numbers[high--];  low < high && numbers[high] == n;  --high)
                ;
            for (final int n = numbers[low++];   low < high && numbers[low]  == n;  ++low)
                ;
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You would also have to add this to the `findAllPairs` method to sort the initial list which is the input:

```
Arrays.sort(input);
```